# error TS2305: Module '"http"' has no exported member 'OutgoingHttpHeaders'. when trying to add electron-updater into electron project

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, node-modules, electron-builder

I am using https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron boilerplate to start electron app. After cloning this, I have made only below two changes in effort to start setting up autoUpdater:

Install electron-updater: `npm install electron-updater --save`

and below line in `main.ts` file:

```
import { autoUpdater } from 'electron-updater';
```

After this when I try try to start application I get below error:

```
node_modules/electron-updater/node_modules/builder-util-runtime/out/httpExecutor.d.ts(2,27): error TS2305: Module '"http"' has no exported member 'OutgoingHttpHeaders'.
node_modules/electron-updater/out/AppUpdater.d.ts(4,10): error TS2305: Module '"http"' has no exported member 'OutgoingHttpHeaders'.
node_modules/electron-updater/out/Provider.d.ts(3,10): error TS2305: Module '"http"' has no exported member 'OutgoingHttpHeaders'.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! angular-electron@2.6.0 build:electron:main: `tsc main.ts --outDir dist && copyfiles package.json dist && cd dist && npm install --prod && cd ..`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-electron@2.6.0 build:electron:main script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/harshveer/.npm/_logs/2018-02-13T09_30_46_752Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! angular-electron@2.6.0 electron:serve: `npm run build:electron:main && electron ./dist --serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-electron@2.6.0 electron:serve script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/harshveer/.npm/_logs/2018-02-13T09_30_46_777Z-debug.log
ERROR: "electron:serve" exited with 2.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! angular-electron@2.6.0 start: `npm-run-all --parallel webpack:watch electron:serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-electron@2.6.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/harshveer/.npm/_logs/2018-02-13T09_30_46_902Z-debug.log
```

Any idea how to fix this,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Importing `electron-updater` module this way: `const autoUpdater = require("electron-updater").autoUpdater` solved the issue. I missed it in the docs:

> Use autoUpdater from electron-updater instead of electron:
>
> `import { autoUpdater } from "electron-updater"`
>
> Or if you don't use ES6: `const autoUpdater = require("electron-updater").autoUpdater`

Answer (score 2):

Discussion [here](https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron/issues/128) if anyone runs into the issue.